# Serialize and Deserialize a BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying a standard interview problem of serializing and deserializing a binary search tree. The original BST has been serialized by using preorder traversal the delimiter as -1 at every null instance.
This is the serialized tree.

```
1297-1-110-1-11413-1-117-1-19
```

This is my code to deserialize the BST,

```
public static Node deserialize(List<Integer> list){
        int index = 0;
        return deserialize(list, index);
    }

    private static Node deserialize(List<Integer> list, int index) {
        if(index == list.size()){
            return null;
        }
        if(list.get(index) == -1){
            index++;
            return null;
        }
        Node root = new Node(list.get(index++));
        root.setLeft(deserialize(list, index));
        root.setRight(deserialize(list, index));

        return root;
    }
```

This however doesn't yield the correct output. On debugging I realized that the value of the index is falling back to its earlier value when the function folds out and that's causing the incorrect result. Is there a way I can maintain the index value across the call stack. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Make parameter a field of the class.

```
public class Deserializer {
    private int index = 0;
    public Node deserialize(List<Integer> list) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Return the parameter from the method.

```
public class DeserializationResult {
    private Node node;
    private int index;
    ... constructor and getters ...
}
```

Update the local variable with the result from the recursive call, whenever a recursive call is made.

```
public DeserializationResult deserialize(List<Integer> list, int index) {
    ...
    DeserializationResult leftResult = deserialize(list, index);
    index = leftResult.getIndex();
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize the index variable outside of the function. Mostly as a class parameter.

Check out this implementation:

```
   // Decodes your encoded data to tree.
   int index = 0;
public TreeNode deserialize(String data) {
    char[] input = data.toCharArray();
    return helper2(input , Integer.MIN_VALUE , Integer.MAX_VALUE);

}
private TreeNode helper2(char[] input , int min , int max) {
    if (index >= input.length || Integer.valueOf(input[index]) >= max || Integer.valueOf(input[index]) <= min) {
        return null;
    }
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(Integer.valueOf(input[index++]));
    root.left = helper2(input , min,Integer.valueOf(root.val));
    root.right = helper2(input , Integer.valueOf(root.val) , max);
    return root;
}
```